# controller function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module, ng-app

I am new to angular js

Controller is not working correctly in my code

i am trying to run following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app >
<head>
    <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data binding</title>
</head>
<body>

    name 
    <br />

    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <input type="text"  data-ng-model="name"/>{{name}}

    <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:city"> {{cust.name | uppercase}}-{{cust.city | lowercase}} </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <script src= "angular/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
        $scope.customers=[
        {name:'John Smith', city:'kashipur'},
        {name:'John fds' , city:'san francisko'},
        { name:'shubham', city:'giarhineg'},
        {name:'batra', city:'world'}];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

but its not giving desire output .

please tell me if i am doing something wrong .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing to add value in your `ng-app` directive that tell angular to run `demoApp` module on the page.

```
ng-app="demoApp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the name of your app.

```
ng-app="demoApp"
```

```js
  var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

  demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
      name: 'John Smith',
      city: 'kashipur'
    }, {
      name: 'John fds',
      city: 'san francisko'
    }, {
      name: 'shubham',
      city: 'giarhineg'
    }, {
      name: 'batra',
      city: 'world'
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
  name
  <br />

  <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />{{name}}

    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:city">{{cust.name | uppercase}}-{{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```