# Why my Plunker Angular JS is not working?

Tags: angularjs, plunker

Can someone tell me why the hell this plunker is not working?
[Sample AngularJS on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/51kCBMXy73sDzvwf3GBe?p=preview)

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>{{userData}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.userData = {
    name: 'Xavier',
    age: 25
  }
});
```

Comment: There is no `ng-app`.

Comment: My bad I guess I should go to sleep... Thanx a lot

Comment: somewhat of a dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687615/controller-function-in-angularjs/30687630#30687630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to put ng-app.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```